# Sharing data between two sets of sibling components in Angular 5

Tags: angular, siblings

Pretty new to Angular. Came from mobile app development.

I know there are so much information teaching how to share data between sibling components. But my question is sharing data between 2 sets of sibling components.

So code-wise, I have 2 components (A and B). When a button in A is clicked, B is updated. But UI-wise, there are 2 sets of this A-B components. So when a button in A1 is clicked, B1 is updated. When a button in A2 is clicked, B2 is updated.

How can I achieve this?

**What I have tried**

In the first place, I used a service to share data. But then found that when A1 was clicked, both B1 and B2 were updated, which is what I don't want. Same for A2 was clicked.

Comment: I'm a little unclear about what you mean by "UI-wise there are 2 sets of these A-B components" - do you mean there is 1 of each component but they are each accessible via 2 routes? If so then you will probably need some logic to use the ActivatedRoute to switch logic of which `Subject` or other `Observable` is updated in the service class. I'd need more details of your code structure exactly what you're trying to achieve though - can you provide an example via stackblitz.com or similar?

Comment: @Timshel basically both component A and B are used twice. So A1 affects only B1, and A2 affects only B2. Everything is in one page so no router is needed. But Simon has solved my problem. Anyways thanks.

Comment: OK, I'd guess the answer from @simon-k below would be the best solution then - pass in a common value to an `@Input()` for each pair of components. You can then pass that value through with triggered events, and the listening component can filter out events where the value doesn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a service to share data between two sibling components is definitely the best way of doing it, the only thing you need to do here is add a key to your components.

```
<comp-a [key]="1"></comp-a>
<comp-b [key]="1"></comp-b>
<comp-a [key]="2"></comp-a>
<comp-b [key]="2"></comp-b>
```

If the components are generated via a `*ngFor`, you could use the index of the loop or perhaps an object id if one is getting bound.

Anyway, when `comp-a` calls the service, you should include the key. When the event that `comp-b` is listening to gets fired, you should include the key in the event and `comp-b` should only respond to it if it matches its own key.

Comment: Thanks. I achieved it by your method. One tiny question is when I fire the event to comp-b from my service, I use .next() and include an object to it because .next() only allow 1 parameter. Is it normal to next() an object? I was thinking if there is a way to include multiple parameters in the next() method.

Comment: Nope, `.next()` can only ever take a single parameter. If you need to pass multiple things then you should indeed use an object. Some people would say that it's best practice to always `.next` an object seeing as it is designed to emit events and a primitive isn't really an event. I personally, however, am happy with using it with void, a primitive or an object as they all work just the same.

Comment: can I pass a string as the key (eg., [key]="hello-world")? When I used number, it worked. When I changed it to string, it returned NaN. I am confused since I assume both should work.

Comment: If you want to use a hard-coded string then you either have to add quotes `[key] ="'hello-world'"` or drop the square brackets `key="hello-world"`, otherwise the expression gets evaluated i.e. `hello - world = NaN`

Answer (score 0):

I think you provided your service at module level and that's why you have single instance.

Provide your service at component level.
Create a wrapper component which holds Both A and B and provide the service at this component level.
Each time the wrapper component is created a new instance of service will be created and that instance will be available only to A and B.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-abwrapper',
    templateUrl: './abwrapper.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./abwrapper.component.scss'],
    providers: [{
        MyServiceToShareData
    }]
})
```